# Method to validate Magento bundled product's "Price as configured."

Tags: magento, bundle, validation

I've been wrestling with Magento 1.5.0.1 for over a week and have yet to find a way to configure either the Catalog or Shopping Cart Price Rules to require product combinations in the bundle to total $59.95 per bundle.

During that same time, and with equally disappointing results, I've searched for a validator - custom or built-in - that would throw a simple javascript alert if the "Price as configured" for a bundled product was not equal to $59.95 (or any other specified amount) when the "Add to Cart" button is pressed. This would prevent the form submission while preserving the customer's selections.

Does anyone have or know of a solution? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would just have an observer on the "Add to Cart before" event. This way you don't have to deal with Javascript or any "hacked" script that could mess up a very important functionality of your site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Fran!

Unfortunately, I am rather new to Magento and need to get this site launched quickly. As a result, I've added some custom variables and an if-then-else statement to the productAddToCartForm.submit function in the javascript starting at line 111 of 
"/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml".

I'll followup on your suggestion shortly.